# Showing a certain complex function is surjective

Tags: complex-analysis

Can you help me show that $f(z)=z+e^{z}$ is surjective onto $\Bbb C$?

The idea is to show that for any $z$, we can construct a closed curve $C$ around $z$ such that $z$ is contained in $f(C)$ with positive winding number. However, I'm not sure which curve I should select. It seems like there aren't many choices: boxes, circles, semicircles, diamond, triangles. However, I'm not knowledgeable enough on the exponential mapping to know what it does to most of these shapes.

Any thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Picard's theorem say that an entire function takes all values, with the possible exception of only one value, say $a$. Suppose this is the case for your function. As you have $f(z+2i\pi)=f(z)+2i\pi$, this show that $f$ do not takes the value $a+2i\pi$, hence two values are not taken, a contradiction.

Comment: We don't know Picard's yet. The idea is as I posted above, I'm just not sure how to apply it.